# no records while using XML Data Islands

Tags: html, xml

Have simple html with xml inside:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>XML Data Islands</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Binding XML Data Islands to Elements</h2>

    <xml id="#myXmlDataSource">
        <items>
            <item id="item1">
                <name>Mocha</name>
                <type>Coffee</type>
                <photo>photos/candles.jpg</photo>
            </item>
            <item id="item2">
                <name>Decaf</name>
                <type>Coffee</type>
                <photo>photos/teacup.jpg</photo>
            </item>
        </items>

    </xml>
    <table datasrc="#myXmlDataSource" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Photo</th>
                <th>
                    Description</th>
                <th>
                    Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img datafld="photo"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span title=  "name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span datafld="type"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately records are not displayed in table. No picture and no text. Where is the problem?

Comment: html doesn't recognise xml

Comment: [XML Data Islands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh801224(v=vs.85).aspx) are an Internet Explorer **only** feature, that was removed in IE10. Which browser are you trying to view this page in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XML Data Islands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh801224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are an Internet Explorer only feature, that was removed in IE10. In it's current form this will **never** work in Chrome or Firefox for example.

However you might want to take a look at [Using XML Data Islands in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) which explains how it might work using HTML5 "data blocks". This would be the more cross-browser compatible solution.

I don't have IE9 but [Updating XML Data Islands with IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552366/updating-xml-data-islands-with-ie9) might help if the following changes don't work for you. I have tested these in IE8 successfully.

There are two small mistakes in your code.

An element `id` should not contain the `#` (that's what the attribute `id` is denoting)

```
<xml id="#myXmlDataSource">
         ^
         remove this
```

And the `<span title= "name"/>` should be `<span datafld="name"/>`.